# How to split optional params?

Tags: python

I have two strings like

```
my_first_string_1
my_second_string
```

which gets split using `a, b, c, d = name.split('_', maxsplit(4))`
But because first and second string have different number of split elements, I get a `ValueError: too many values to unpack`. I don't care about the trailing `_1`, how do I call `split` for both strings?

Comment: Please post a working script that demonstrates the problem. Right now you don't show code that would fail this way. Presumably you are assigning the result of the split to a list of variables and that''s what raises the error. If so, show it.

Comment: `split` itself doesn't cause that `ValueError`. Please provide a [mcve]`

Comment: `maxsplit` limits the number of fields *produced*; it does not pad the return value  up to the specified value.

Comment: Are you guaranteed to have at least 3 things after the split?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the docs, [Assignment Statements](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements): *If the target list contains one target prefixed with an asterisk, called a “starred” target: The object must be an iterable with at least as many items as there are targets in the target list, minus one. The first items of the iterable are assigned, from left to right, to the targets before the starred target. The final items of the iterable are assigned to the targets after the starred target. A list of the remaining items in the iterable is then assigned to the starred target (the list can be empty)*

that's a rather long-winded way to say that you can include a starred variable in a target list to vacuum up any extra data. Traditionally, the name "_" is used for variables you don't care about, so you can write your split as

```
a, b, c, *_ = name.split("_", maxsplit=3)
```

Now `_` will hold a list of zero or more values from the split. Note that it is assumed you will always have at least 3 values from the split.

Comment: Not that it matters much but because you've included `maxsplit=3` that means `_` will include a list of zero or exactly one value

Comment: @chrislondon - Right. Technically the split can have anywhere from `1` to `maxsplit+1` values but we are assuming that there are always at least 3 values split out. That leaves either 0 or 1 additional items in `_`. I said "zero or more" simply because its a more generic way to state what's going on with the starred item in the target list.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using max split you can do the following:

```
name.split('_')[:3]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do `name.split('_')[:3]` like the other answer has suggested.  I notice that you are also missing a parenthesis at the end of your `.split()`.
They do essentially the same thing, which is split up until a certain index (which is 3).
If each string is a separate variable, you can do this:

```py
first = 'my_first_string_1'
second = 'my_second_string'
first = first.split('_')[:3]
second = second.split('_')
print(first)
print(second)
```